# Proving the finiteness of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Really stuck in this question:

Let $f: [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $g: [1, +\infty) \rightarrow [-\infty, +\infty] $ be non-negative continuous functions such that for all $\epsilon >0$,
\begin{equation}
g( 1+ \epsilon ) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\epsilon -1} f(x) \, dx.
\end{equation}

Show that if $g(1) < +\infty$ and there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\sup_{x \geq 0} x^{\delta} f(x) < + \infty$, then $g( 1+ \epsilon) < + \infty$, for all $0 \leq \epsilon < \delta$.

(I know that the integral should be split into two parts, i.e. from $ 0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $\infty$, but don't know how to proceed from there.)

Comment: Is there some condition missing? Is the definition of $g$ correct? If $f(x)=x^{-\delta}$, $g(1+\epsilon)=\infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre The missing conditions are added. You are right about this. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ it is bounded. Let $M=\sup_{0\le x\le1}f(x)$ and $C=\sup_{x\ge1}x^{\delta}f(x)$. Then
$$\begin{align}
g(1+\epsilon)&=\int_0^1x^{\epsilon-1}f(x)\,dx+\int_1^\infty x^{\epsilon-1}f(x)\,dx\\
&\le M\int_0^1x^{\epsilon-1}\,dx+C\int_1^\infty x^{\epsilon-1-\delta}f(x)\,dx\\
&=\frac{M}{\epsilon}+\frac{C}{\delta-\epsilon}.
\end{align}$$